# Can anyone identify this 6-pin SMD integrated circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, solar-charge-controller

Can anyone please identify this 6-pin SMD integrated circuit, or tell what it does? I could not find it by the code written on it.

It is from a solar charger controller and I need to replace it.

[image]

Comment: By the way, replacing that stands a small chance of helping you, only. The thing burnt for a reason, and that's probably a failure in a power semiconductor or a short circuit. Your desoldering job below looks terrifying, so I'd bet this whole board is simply broken and can't be repaired.

Answer (score 2):

Could be MP2459. The pinout seems to match your board.

Datasheet says AEQ top marking but isn’t 100 % clear on other markings and shows an example with four characters.
[image]

[Some Chinese vendor](https://www.google.se/amp/s/world.taobao.com/item-amp/610407268071.htm)

[datasheet](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2459/)

Comment: hi .Thanks for your guidance

Comment: You might want to expand your answer.  The chip is a buck regulator and it fits the circuit on the PCB.